# GitLab SonarQube CI/CD variables are not passed to the Pipeline

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab

I was trying to integrate the GitLab CI/CD with SonarQube 8.1 based on the following documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-cicd/.

I tried to use the SonarScanner for Maven sample configurations

```
image: maven:latest
variables:
  SONAR_TOKEN: "your-sonarqube-token"
  SONAR_HOST_URL: "http://your-sonarqube-url"
  GIT_DEPTH: 0
sonarqube-check:
  script:
    - mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
```

The problem is that it looks like the SONAR_HOST_URL, and probably, the SONAR_TOKEN is ignored for unclear reason. When looking at the pipeline log I get

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project sonar-java-test: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to workaround this by setting the variables using the gitlab (12.3.2) CI/CD variables, but it doesn’t work

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to modify your maven command adding `-Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN` (even it's not in the doc) ?

Comment: That helped, thanks! now I end up with certification issue, but that's a good sign.

Comment: @Nicolas Pepinster If you post this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation seems not up-to-date.

You should add `-Dsonar.host.url` and `-Dsonar.host.url` arguments to the maven command to ovveride the default settings :

```
image: maven:latest
variables:
  SONAR_TOKEN: "your-sonarqube-token"
  SONAR_HOST_URL: "http://your-sonarqube-url"
  GIT_DEPTH: 0
sonarqube-check:
  script:
    - mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Protected` toggle in the `Gitlab > Variables` screenshot refers to *Protected Branches* and *Tags*. It does not mean the variable is protected.

It is the `Masked` toggle that protects the variable being leaked into logs etc.

[image: Gitlab > Variables > Protected]

gitlab-ci understands the variables `SONAR_TOKEN` and `SONAR_HOST_URL`

Reference: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-cicd/

Comment: I have to admit that the protect/masked definitions are very confusing +1